# Question about backwards compatibility of jquery

Tags: jquery, backwards-compatibility

I know jquery have backwardscompatibility files.

But if you link to this specific version: http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js you don't need backwardscompatibility files. 
I want to know if http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js also is going to work with newer browserversions. Then I don't need to upgrade my jquery to newer versions with the risk that the website doesn't work well anymore.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm sure there won't be issues with newer browser against an older jquery version. Jquery itself is pure javascript - so I guess this shouldn't be a problem.

You'll probably getting into trouble when trying to implement newer features of you page that may require new jquery plugins...